# Timing with Internet Explorer 7/8 - Chart not shown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have one Highchart and some other functions in one script. It works fine in Firefox and IE > 8, but with IE 7/8 there is a timing problem, the chart is not shown at all.

My workaround is

```
setTimeout( function() {    
   .. my other functions
}, 5000 );
```

but it is not a good practice and even not sure, if 5000 is enough in every case.

Is there a way to detect, when Highchart is ready and the script can go on with other functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the [chart load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").highcharts({
        events: {
            load: function () { myOtherFunctions(); }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't help. In my case, the chart will not be loaded without setTimeout, so the chart load event doesn't fire. Is there any other chance?

Comment: I see - I have updated the example to ensure the code runs when the document is ready - this should help with that.